# Drawing a Month From a Date

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'm wondering how I can draw the month and year from a string date in the form MM/DD/YYYY.

I've tried lubridate but it isn't working, nor is anything else.

Comment: try `lubridate::month`

Answer (score 3):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

date = "2012-10-03"
ymd(date)

ymd(date) %>% day()
[1] 3

ymd(date) %>% month()
[1] 10
```

For the format MM/DD/YYYY use:

```
date = "12/22/2013" 
mdy(date) %>% month()
[1] 12
```

Comment: That is not the date format that the OP requested. Should be MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: use mdy() to parse such a date

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format`

```
month <- format(as.Date('07/04/2010', format = '%m/%d/%Y'), '%m') # or %b or %B
year <- format(as.Date('07/04/2010', format = '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y') # or %y
```